# Use linq to filter by property of subcollection

Tags: c#, linq

```
class Store
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<AnnualData> annualData { get; set; }
}

class AnnualData
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, double> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get the requested stores and the requested years' data.  I can filter stores easily:

```
List<int> storeIDs = new List<int> {12, 13, 14};
List<Store> stores = allData.Stores.Where(s => storeIDs.Contains(s.ID)).ToList();
```

But I can't figure out how to further filter by a list of years.

```
List<int> years = new List<int> {2012, 2013, 2014};
stores = allData.Stores.Where(s => storeIDs.Contains(s.ID)).?????
```

Tried Any/All/Contains but I'm obviously not understanding Linq well enough. Thanks in advance.

**Update after proposed solutions by Selmann & Timothy**
Using your examples I still see all 3 years for store 1 in the output - I want to see only 2007 in t his case:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Store> allData = new List<Store> {                 
            new Store { ID = 1,
                        annualData = new List<AnnualData> {
                            new AnnualData {
                                Year = 2006,
                                Data = new Dictionary<string, double>{{"Value2006", 1.0}}
                            },
                            new AnnualData {
                                Year = 2007,
                                Data = new Dictionary<string, double>{{"Value2007", 1.1}}
                            },
                            new AnnualData {
                                Year = 2008,
                                Data = new Dictionary<string, double>{{"Value2008", 1.2}}
                            }
                        }
            }
        };

        List<int> storeIDs = new List<int> { 1 };
        List<int> years = new List<int> { 2007 };

        var stores = allData.Where(s => storeIDs.Contains(s.ID) &&
                                     s.annualData.Any(x => years.Contains(x.Year)));

        foreach (Store s in stores)
            foreach (AnnualData a in s.annualData)
                Console.WriteLine(a.Year);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stores = allData.Stores
    .Where(s => storeIDs.Contains(s.ID))
    .Select(s => new Store
    {
        ID = s.ID,
        annualData = s.annualData
            .Where(x => years.Contains(x.Year))
            .ToList()
    });
```

Comment: Same result as for Selmann - I'm getting all years rather than only those I want.

Comment: @Graeme I have changed the answer to match your new specification.  The question wasn't so clear before.

Comment: That second where should be a select.

Comment: Thanks Timothy and MrBlue. That's exactly what I need. Looks like contains and any do the same job in a different way?

Comment: @Graeme `enumerable.Contains(item)` is conceptually equivalent to `enumerable.Any(x => x == item)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Any` method:

```
stores = allData.Stores.Where(s => storeIDs.Contains(s.ID) && 
                                 s.annualData.Any(x => years.Contains(x.Year)));
```

Comment: I'm hoping to get back only the required years. I'm still getting all years with this solution. See my edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't select a `Store` object where the list of `AnnualData` objects only includes those where the year is 2007 because no such object exists.  The reason you're getting all years is because you're selecting a `Store` object where any of the `AnnualData` objects in the list have the year 2007 - but it's still returning the whole list.

To get a `Store` with a list of only the `AnnualData` items you want, you'll need to create it...

```
var stores = allData.Where(s => storeIDs.Contains(s.ID))
                    .Select(s =>
                        new Store { ID = s.ID, annualData = s.annualData.Where(x => years.Any(y => y == x.Year)).ToList() } )
                    .ToList();
```